# Cant receive code

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hey guys sorry to ask this, but I am stumped, I want the code to go to the pages with the action when the radio button is clicked, like stupid radio button to stupid.php here's the form

```
 <form name = "quoted" method="get">
 <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
 <textarea class = "actual_quote" name = "actual_quote" required="required" placeholder = "Write the question here!"></textarea><br><br><br>
 <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
<h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
  <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupid" id = "x" checked="checked" action = "stupid.php" />    <span>stupid</span></label><br>
    <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupider" id = "x" action = "stupider.php" /> <span>stupider</span>    </label><br>
    <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupidest" id = "x" action = "stupidest.php" />    <span>stupidest</span></label>
  </div>
  <input id = "submit1" type="submit"><br>
 </form>
```

and here's the php on each of the pages, stupid, stupider, and stupidest, the php error is saying that actual-quote and poster are not identified indexes, help?

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Question.</h2>
    <div class="checkboxes"><?= !empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : '' ?>
    </div>

    </div>

 <div class="top-submit"><?php echo '&#8220;' . (!empty($_GET['actual_quote']) ?  $_GET['actual_quote'] : '') . '&#8221;'; $actual_quote = $_GET['actual_quote'];?>
 </div>
 <div class="poster"><?php echo "-" .  (!empty($_GET['poster']) ? $_GET['poster'] :''); $poster =  $_GET['poster'];?>
 <div class = "like">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "color:green;">Like</a>
 <p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
 </div>
 <div class = "dislike">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right; color:red;">Dislike</a>
 <p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
 </div>
  </div>
 <?php 
 "INSERT INTO submissions(top-submit, poster)
 VALUES ($actual_quote, $poster)";
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I am sorry to ask, but I have been trying for an hour and I have run out of ideas. Any suggestions is GREATLY welcomed.

Comment: `<form name = "quoted" action = "stupidweb3.php" method="get">`

Comment: I am sorry to ask, but is the error in there?

Comment: yes.You have an unwanted HTMl tag(form)

Answer (score 0):

try remove form `action = "stupidweb3.php"` to `action = "stupidweb3.php"`
Also check radio buttons code(keep unique id and remove action)

```
<form name = "quoted"  action = "stupidweb3.php" method="get">
 <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
 <textarea class = "actual_quote" name = "actual_quote" required="required" placeholder = "Write the question here!"></textarea><br><br><br>
 <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
<h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
  <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" id="x" value="stupid" />    <span>stupid</span></label><br>
    <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" id="x1" value="stupider" /> <span>stupider</span>    </label><br>
    <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" id="x2" value="stupidest"  />    <span>stupidest</span></label>
  </div>
  <input id = "submit1" type="submit"><br>
 </form>
```

and stupidweb3.php

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Question.</h2>
    <div class="checkboxes"><?php echo (!empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : ''); ?>
    </div>

    </div>

 <div class="top-submit"><?php echo '&#8220;' . (!empty($_GET['actual_quote']) ?  $_GET['actual_quote'] : '') . '&#8221;'; $actual_quote = $_GET['actual_quote'];?>
 </div>
 <div class="poster"><?php echo "-" .  (!empty($_GET['poster']) ? $_GET['poster'] :''); $poster =  $_GET['poster'];?>
 <div class = "like">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "color:green;">Like</a>
 <p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
 </div>
 <div class = "dislike">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right; color:red;">Dislike</a>
 <p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
 </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

and where you run query and where you set `$actual_quote, $poster` it should be like

```
<?php 
$sql = "INSERT INTO submissions(top-submit, poster)
 VALUES ('$actual_quote', '$poster')";
?>
```

set both variable and run your query